# String matching algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, c++11

I have been going through algorithms and data structures and recently came across string matching algorithms.  I have not yet wrapped my head around the significance KMP algorithm so I came up with the function below.  Is it really efficient or is there a better approach?

```
bool simplePatternMatch(const std::string &text, const std::string &pattern){
    //return true if pattern occurs otherwise false
    auto pat_it = pattern.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator it = text.begin();
    for(; it != text.end(); it++){
        if(*it == *pat_it){
            auto internal_it = it + 1;
            pat_it++;
            for(; internal_it != text.end();internal_it++){
                if( *internal_it == *pat_it)
                    pat_it++;
                else{
                    //a partial match occured so begin again to look for a match
                    pat_it = pattern.begin();
                    break;
                }
                if(pat_it == pattern.end())
                    return true;

            }

        }
    }
    //if we reach here there was no match
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Will fail for `simplePatternMatch("CCAT", "CAT")`

Comment: I have fixed the bug in the function but I already have a feeling it is inefficient.Well atleast I see why we need the KMP algorithm:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code Style

#### Whitespace and Braces

Be consistent in your usage of whitespace and braces. `for` and `if` statments should have a space between the keyword, parentheses, and opening brace (if using K&R style braces). Also, don't omit braces in an `if`, then include them in the `else`. For example:

```
if( *internal_it == *pat_it)
    pat_it++;
else{ // ...
```

Becomes:

```
if(*internal_it == *pat_it) {
    pat_it++;
} else { // ...
```

#### Reduce Variable Scope

`it` and `internal_it` are both declared outside their respective `for` statement, but are not referenced outside of it. Declaring them inside the `for` statement limits their scope to within the `for` loop, reducing opportunities for them to be misused. You can also use `auto` for type deduction, saving you the necessity of typing long iterator type names.

#### Reduce Nesting

Your code contains many nested `if` and `for` statements. This can make the code hard to read. If you have an `if` statement wrapping the entire loop body, you can reduce the level of nesting by inverting the condition and breaking early:

```
if(*it == *pat_it){
    // loop body
}
```

Becomes:

```
if (*it != *pat_it) {
    continue;
}
// loop body
```

## Simplify, Simplify

Your inner `for` loop has almost exactly the same bounds as the outer loop. This can be simplified to a single loop over `text` and `pattern` each:

```
bool simplePatternMatch(const std::string &text, const std::string &pattern)
{
    // handle empty-string case
    if (pattern.empty() || text.empty())
    {
        return pattern.empty() && text.empty();
    }

    for(auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); it++) {
        auto pat_it = pattern.begin();
        while (pat_it != pattern.end() && *it == *pat_it) {
            ++it;
            ++pat_it;
        }
        if (pat_it == pattern.end()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //if we reach here there was no match
    return false;
}
```

You could change the `while` to a `for` and increment `it` and `pat_it` in the increment statement, but I find this more readable. Writing it this way also makes it explicit that there is a loop over each of your string arguments, which makes analyzing complexity much easier.

But wait! All that iterator comparison is complicated. Wouldn't it be nice if there was another way? Turns out, there is [`std::mismatch()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch), which is essentially what the inner loop does. Then the loop can be simplified:

```
for (auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); ++it) {
    const auto mismatches = std::mismatch(pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), it);
    if (mismatches.first == pattern.end()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

## Algorithm

Now that your function has been simplified a bit, it is easier to see that you have written a naive pattern match, which has complexity \$\mathcal{O}(mn)\$, where **m** is your pattern length, and **n** is the string length. You can improve upon this by implementing one of the well-known pattern-matching algorithms, like [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) or [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). I leave this as an exercise to you, both because it would make this answer too long, and it would be a good candidate for another question on Code Review.